# How do I retrieve the root window properties for a display in X11?

Tags: x11

The PulseAudio FAQ has [this sentence](http://pulseaudio.org/wiki/FAQ#HowdothePulseAudiolibrariesdecidewheretoconnectto):

> If $DISPLAY is set, the library tries to connect to that server and looks for the root window property PULSE_SERVER for the host to connect to.

For a given $DISPLAY, how can I retrieve this and other root window properties, from, say, bash or Python?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the [xprop](http://www.xfree86.org/current/xprop.1.html) command is what you're looking for:

```
xprop -display $DISPLAY -root
```